# Adding GDPR Consent Dialog to a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, admob

Is there anything available to add a GDPR consent Dialog using Flutter? The [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) plugin has some properties for adding nonPersonalizedAds or not but thats about it.

I haven't noticed an SDK or anything for Flutter like they have for [Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent). Has anyone added a consent somehow on their own or did it separately for Android and then iOS

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i write simple library for flutter that show GDPR dialog for user.
This library works only with android platform now. IOS version coming soon.

Link:
https://pub.dev/packages/gdpr_dialog#-readme-tab-